# not able to resolve import org.springframework.amqp.*; statement in my spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm trying to use the spring apmq core package in my spring boot project. I have added the dependency in my pom file but for some weird reason the import statement for org.springframework.amqp is not getting resolved. Any idea why is this happening??

Here is the dependency I'm using in my pom file-->

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-amqp</artifactId>
<version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And this is the import statement I'm using in my config files

```
import org.springframework.amqp.*;
```

I've already tried invalidating the caches and restarting intellij and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Why don't you use spring-boot-starter-amqp?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Can't. The repositiory that I'm allowed to use doesn't have it. Besides, the spring-amqp should contain the core packages right?

Comment: That does not make sense to me. You are using Spring Boot and are not allowed to use the Spring Boot Starters?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli can you provide the exact dependency ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Spring Boot Starter for AMQP instead:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Used this. but still the import statement is not working. This clearly is an intellij issue